# Multiple responses from a single HTTP request

Tags: java, http, servlets, request, response

I have a Java Web Application.  When a user clicks on a "Retrieve" button they expect to see 3 new tabs open in their browser with a different PDF document in each tab.  The PDF documents are generated from the server.

I know this can be accomplished by sending 3 requests from Javascript within the html page, but does anybody know of a way to accomplish this with a single request to the server or is that not allowed?

Comment: HTTP is limited to 1 response per request.

Comment: My opinion: having 3 tabs opened doesn't sound like a good user experience.  Seems like there should be 3 different buttons so the user can get the specific pdf needed, or 1 pdf which combines all 3 if the user usually needs all of them.